# Plotly/Python creation of the nested x-axis bar-chart

Tags: plotly, bar-chart, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I was wondering if Plotly can start support for nested X /multiple X axis?
For instance if one is using standard “tip” data, adding a capability as implemented in (fivecents plot, JMP or Origin ) would be beneficial.
i.e.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib inline
import fivecentplots as fcp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os, sys, pdb
osjoin = os.path.join
db = pdb.set_trace
fcp.boxplot(df=df, y=‘tip’, groups=[‘time’, ‘sex’, ‘day’], legend=‘smoker’)
```

[image]

would generate:
nested X-axis bar-chart

If this capability already exist - please add a comment.

Comment: I am not sure if Plotly supports a multidimensional xaxis for more than 2 dimensions. any plotly experts want to chime in?

Comment: Yes, @DerekO, to the best of my knowledge this functionality is not supported by plotly.

Comment: I recommend posting this question in Plotly community forum here: https://community.plotly.com/

Comment: Thanks Derek & Hamzah, this was done some time back: https://community.plotly.com/t/box-plot-with-nested-x-axis/55800

Comment: I believe that using a groupby and creating a separate trace for each boxplot, you could achieve something similar to what is being shown, but you would have to create the multidimensional x-axis labels yourself probably using annotations and admittedly, this would be a ton of work.

Answer (score 3):

It's doable, but takes a lot more steps than the method you're currently using. One solution to achieving this with plotly is by creating subplots with multidimensional axis, one for Lunch and one for Dinner, with zero space in between so it looks like one single plot.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

df = px.data.tips()

#set order for days
days = CategoricalDtype(
    ['Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    ordered=True
    )

df['day'] = df['day'].astype(days)

#sort df
df.sort_values(['time', 'sex', 'day'], inplace=True)

#create framework
fig = make_subplots(rows=1,
            cols=2,
            shared_yaxes=True,
            horizontal_spacing=0,
            column_widths=[7/11, 4/11])

#create "Dinner" boxplots
fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=[df['sex'][df['time']=='Dinner'].tolist(), df['day'][df['time']=='Dinner'].tolist()],
             y=df['tip'][df['time']=='Dinner'],
             boxpoints=False,
             pointpos=0,
             line=dict(color='gray',
                   width=1),
             fillcolor='white',
             showlegend=False),
          row=1,
          col=1)
#add "Dinner" smokers
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[df['sex'][(df['time']=='Dinner') & (df['smoker']=='Yes')].tolist(), df['day'][(df['time']=='Dinner') & (df['smoker']=='Yes')].tolist()],
             y=df['tip'][(df['time']=='Dinner') & (df['smoker']=='Yes')],
             mode='markers',
             marker=dict(color='red',
                     symbol='circle-open',
                     size=10),
             name='Yes'
             ),
          row=1,
          col=1)

#add "Dinner" non-smokers
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[df['sex'][(df['time']=='Dinner') & (df['smoker']=='No')].tolist(), df['day'][(df['time']=='Dinner') & (df['smoker']=='No')].tolist()],
             y=df['tip'][(df['time']=='Dinner') & (df['smoker']=='No')],
             mode='markers',
             marker=dict(color='green',
                     symbol='cross-thin-open',
                     size=10),
             name='No'
             ),
          row=1,
          col=1)

df_mean = df[['sex', 'day', 'tip']][df['time']=='Dinner'].groupby(['sex', 'day']).mean().reset_index().dropna()

#add "Dinner" mean line
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[df_mean['sex'].tolist(), df_mean['day'].tolist()],
             y=df_mean['tip'].tolist(),
             showlegend=False,
             marker=dict(color='black')
             ),
          row=1,
          col=1)

#create "Lunch" boxplots
fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=[df['sex'][df['time']=='Lunch'].tolist(), df['day'][df['time']=='Lunch'].tolist()],
             y=df['tip'][df['time']=='Lunch'],
             boxpoints=False,
             pointpos=0,
             line=dict(color='gray',
                   width=1),
             fillcolor='white',
             showlegend=False),
          row=1,
          col=2)
#add "Lunch" smokers
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[df['sex'][(df['time']=='Lunch') & (df['smoker']=='Yes')].tolist(), df['day'][(df['time']=='Lunch') & (df['smoker']=='Yes')].tolist()],
             y=df['tip'][(df['time']=='Lunch') & (df['smoker']=='Yes')],
             mode='markers',
             marker=dict(color='red',
                     symbol='circle-open',
                     size=10),
             showlegend=False
             ),
          row=1,
          col=2)
#add "Lunch" non-smokers
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[df['sex'][(df['time']=='Lunch') & (df['smoker']=='No')].tolist(), df['day'][(df['time']=='Lunch') & (df['smoker']=='No')].tolist()],
             y=df['tip'][(df['time']=='Lunch') & (df['smoker']=='No')],
             mode='markers',
             marker=dict(color='green',
                     symbol='cross-thin-open',
                     size=10),
             showlegend=False
             ),
          row=1,
          col=2)

df_mean = df[['sex', 'day', 'tip']][df['time']=='Lunch'].groupby(['sex', 'day']).mean().reset_index().dropna()

#add "Lunch" mean line
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[df_mean['sex'].tolist(), df_mean['day'].tolist()],
             y=df_mean['tip'].tolist(),
             showlegend=False,
             marker=dict(color='black')
             ),
          row=1,
          col=2)

fig.update_xaxes(title='Dinner', col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(title='Lunch', col=2)
fig.update_yaxes(title='tip', col=1)
fig.update_layout(legend_title='Smoker')
fig.show()
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: Thanks for the response Amance, this is far more complex than 12 lines of code. I think that the person who coded 5C plots (https://endangeredoxen.github.io/fivecentplots/0.5.1/) made it quite user friendly. I only wish that he added support for plotly as he did for Bokeh.

Comment: @PKuca Agreed! Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.